# Az Data Factory: The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to convert a `string` to a `int` data type in Azure Data Factory `Data Flow` activity to set a parameter?

I have been trying to get a value from a `json` file in a gen2 data lake:

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "schema_name": "my_schema",
        "table_name": "my_table",
        "reserved_space_MB": 138.808,
        "unused_space_MB": 1.392,
        "data_space_MB": 136.848,
        "index_space_MB": 0.568,
        "row_count": 916300
    },
    ...
}
```

But got this error in the last activty:

```
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "_split_file_from_table",
    "details": ""
}
```

I have been following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) and also these stack overflow questions:
[Azure Data Factory split file by file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944366/azure-data-factory-split-file-by-file-size/62955643#62955643)
[Convert Row Count to INT in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067826/convert-row-count-to-int-in-azure-data-factory)
But I'm getting the same error no matter what I do.

**How to reproduce**

1. Use a `Lookup` activity in a pipeline:

[image]

2. start variable `table_size_var` as a string data type

[image]

3. `Set Variable` activity to get the `data_space_MB` value:
   `@string(activity('read_json').output.firstRow.data_space_MB)`

[image]

4. Set parameter `table_size_mb` in a `Data Flow`:

[image]

5. Set the value from the variable `table_size_var` to the parameter `table_size_mb`:
   `@int(variables('table_size_var'))`

[image]

6. Run the pipeline - results:

**lookup**
[image]

**Set Variable**
[image]

**Data Flow**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and get the same error.

The `int()` function only works for covert int string to integer, the parameter must be an int String!
For example string `'100'` to integer `100`. It can not convert decimal string `'136.848'` to integer `136.848`.

I'm using `int()` and `split()` function to get integer `138` , then the pipeline works well.
Expression:

```
@int(split(variables('num'),'.')[1])
```

1. The variable will split into an array, `'138'` and `'848'`, using `[1]` to get the first element.
2. Then using `int()` to convert `'138'` to integer `138`.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I tried with `float` and `decimal` data types with the same error. Thanks!